# How to exclude an anonyomous class from jacoco?

Tags: java, jacoco, anonymous-class

I am seeing class `CacheConfig.new CacheLoader() {...}` in my jacoco report. Is there a way to exclude it?

Answer (score 7):

To exclude all anonymous classes in `CacheConfig`, it should work if you exclude `CacheConfig$1*.class`, `CacheConfig$2*.class`, `CacheConfig$3*.class`, `CacheConfig$4*.class`, `CacheConfig$5*.class`, `CacheConfig$6*.class`, `CacheConfig$7*.class`, `CacheConfig$8*.class`, `CacheConfig$9*.class` as anonymous classes are compiled to `CacheConfig$1.class`, `CacheConfig$2.class` and so on.

Excluding `CacheConfig$*.class` will not work, as it would exclude all inner classes, not only anonymous ones. If you want to exclude all inner classes, `CacheConfig$*.class` is ok to be used.

If you only want to exclude this one anonymous class, you can of course also exclude `CacheConfig$1.class` or what number it has. You can see this from the link that the label `CacheConfig.new CacheLoader() {...}` in the report is pointing at. But be aware, if you add another anonymous class before this one in `CacheConfig`, numbers will shift accordingly.

Comment: Your answer helped, but I'm not sure what this part means, " You can see this from the link that the label ..." what link / label are you referring to?

Comment: The question was about a JaCoCo report. That is what I'm referring to. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Adding `**/*$*.*` in excluded list ignores all anonymous binders and classes in your classes